# Search Key Value pair among two separate dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, full-text-search

Below is the code snippet, I'm trying to filter a list of dictionaries based on a filter rule. Since the filter rule will change & i don't want to hard code. If the  below snippet returns true I'll save that dictionary in a seaprate dictionary to perform further actions. this code snippet is returning False since it's iterating as many times depending on the number of keys in big_dict. Is there a way to iterate the big_dict based only on the values of the small_dict. If someone could help me in this.

```
new_dict={}
big_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2,'c': 3,'d':4,'e':5}
small_dict = {'filter_rule': {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'e': 5}}
for key, value in small_dict.items():
    if key in 'filter_rule':
        res = all( value.get( big_key, None ) == big_val for big_key, big_val in big_dict.items() )
        if res == True:
        new_dict = big_dict
        print(new_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_dict={}
big_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2,'c': 3,'d':4,'e':5}
small_dict = {'filter_rule': {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'e': 5}}
for key, value in small_dict.items():
    if key in 'filter_rule':
        for k,v in small_dict.get(key)
            if k in big_dict.keys()
               if v == big_dict.get(k):
                   good = 1
                   continue;
               else:
                   good = 0
                   break;
```

Comment: You should also supply an explanation to your code. This way, your answer will be more general and will help other people with similar problems.